# list integers,for each index find the product of every integer except the that index

Tags: c#, linq

You have a list of integers, and for each index you want to find the product of every integer except the integer at that index.

i cant understand what is wrong with my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int outcome = 1;
            int removed;
            List<int> list = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 6, 4, 6, 4, 9, 
        8, 3, 1 });
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                removed=list[j] ;
                list.RemoveAt(j);
                 for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                 {
                     outcome *= list[i];
                 }
                 list.Add(removed);
                 Console.WriteLine(outcome);
            }
              Console.ReadKey();
        }
     }

    }
```

Comment: What is wrong then? What doesnt it do

Comment: You alter the list (`RemoveAt`) and then loop over it....

Comment: For your given input `list` what output are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

I think what's going wrong is that you're defining outcome to be 1 only at the start of the program - as far as I can tell you want to start it inside the first for loop (`for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)`).

Would it not be easier to find the product of every integer in the list, and then divide this by the integer at the index?

```
for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) 
{
    outcome = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
        outcome *= list[i];

    outcome = outcome / list[j];
    Console.WriteLine(outcome);
}
```

Comment: it was mention on the problem set"Do not use division in your solution."

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you never reset `outcome` after each iteration, so `outcome` will just getting bigger and bigger. A simple fix for your program is:

```
        int removed;
        List<int> list = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 6, 4, 6, 4, 9, 
    8, 3, 1 });
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            removed=list[j] ;
            list.RemoveAt(j);
            int outcome = 1;

             for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
             {
                 outcome *= list[i];
             }
             list.Add(removed);
             Console.WriteLine(outcome);
        }
```

However, you can improve the efficiency significantly by implement this algorithm (I don't write the cod for you, but you can easily write one yourself)

1. Compute the products of all element (call it `product`)
2. Loop through each element, at each index `j`, print the value of
   `product/list[j]`

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. You are changing the order of the items in the list while you are iterating over them.
2. You are not resetting `outcome` to 1 inside the outer loop, so it keeps getting bigger and bigger.

You could consider a different approach:

1. Compute the product of all the numbers in the list.
2. For each number in the list, divide the total product by that number to give the product excluding that number.

You should probably use a `long` to hold the product in the general case, to help avoid overflow (although a long enough list with big enough numbers could still overflow a `long`).

You can calculate the product using Linq's `Aggregate` as follows:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(new[] {1, 2, 6, 4, 6, 4, 9, 8, 3, 1});
long prod = list.Aggregate(1L, (p, v) => p * v); // 1L means it will use long.
```

Then you can calculate the product excluding each element of the list as follows:

```
foreach (var i in list)
    Console.WriteLine(prod / i);
```

Note that this will NOT work if any elements of the list are zero. In that event, every resultant product should be zero.

Answer (score 0):

You must edit `for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)`. Because you run `list.RemoveAt(j);` then list of count is 9;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int outcome = 1;
    int removed;
    List<int> list = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 6, 4, 6, 4, 9, 
8, 3, 1 });
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        removed = list[j];
        list.RemoveAt(j);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            outcome *= list[i];
        }
        list.Add(removed);
        Console.WriteLine(outcome);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

- You alterate the list you are looping over
- You don't reset your result variable
- You don't iterate the whole list (there are ten elements but you only iterate over 9)

A working example could be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
{
    int output = list.Where((val, idx) => idx != j).Aggregate((a, x) => a * x);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

You removing item at index, and adding to end list.
Don't modify list, just skip needed item. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestList
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double outcome = 1;
            List<double> list = new List<double>(new double[] { 1, 2, 6, 4, 6, 4, 9, 8, 3, 1 });
            //List<int> list = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (i == j)
                        continue;
                    outcome *= list[j];
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(outcome);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . .");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Use double because the values so high!

Comment: thanx Sir your answer was the best with respect to all other participant,thans Sir :*